# How to detect and extract text from the box model forms

Tags: python-3.x

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from boxdetect import config
from boxdetect.pipelines import get_boxes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image1 = cv2.imread('kyc_sample1.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh4 = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
cv2.imshow('Kyc', thresh4)
cfg = config.PipelinesConfig()

cfg.width_range = (30,55)
cfg.height_range = (25,40)
cfg.scaling_factors = [0.7]
cfg.wh_ratio_range = (0.5, 1.7)
cfg.group_size_range = (2, 100)
cfg.dilation_iterations = 0
rects, grouping_rects, image, output_image = get_boxes(
    thresh4, cfg=cfg, plot=False)

print(grouping_rects)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.imshow(output_image)
plt.show()
```

Required solution:

```
Name: Mr William Smith Jons , PAN: 577634563744
```

Is there any solution to detect the text from the box and extract the text based on the detection of boxes. I have used boxdetection method in python to detect the text form the form

[image: Sample Image]